# Can ZFC be proven to be consistent in this way?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I was reading the wikipedia article of [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) and I saw that it has been proven that ZFC + "there exists an inaccessible cardinal" (which I'll call "ZFC + IC") proves that ZFC is consistent.

What would happen if we took ZFC + $\neg$IC and proved that ZFC is consistent with it?

Would that mean that ZFC is consistent in general? Would we also have to prove that both ZFC + IC and ZFC + $\neg$IC are consistent?

I don't know much about set theory and cardinals, so I would appreciate it if the answer doesn't involve too many fancy terms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be a proof that ZFC shows that ZFC is consistent. Godel showed that there is no such proof. (Unless of course ZFC is in fact inconsistent, in which case all these proofs exist, with all but the first one trivial...)

Comment: This is of course correct. Note, however, that there **is** a sense in which both a statement and its negation can increase the consistency strength of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, even if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent: there is a sentence $\varphi$ such that $$\mathsf{ZFC+Con(ZFC+\neg\varphi)}\not\vdash \mathsf{Con(ZFC+\varphi)}\quad\mbox{and}\quad\mathsf{ZFC+Con(ZFC+\varphi)}\not\vdash \mathsf{Con(ZFC+\neg\varphi)}.$$ So we do have to be rather careful when talking about consistency strength. See (there proved for PA) Theorem 3 of [Hamkins' recent non-linearity paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.07445.pdf)

Comment: So that means that ZFC + $\neg$IC can't prove that ZFC is consistent?

Comment: @AndrésRomero Assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is in fact consistent, **yes**, that's exactly what this means. More generally, for any "reasonable" theory $T$ and any sentence $\varphi$, if $T+\varphi\vdash Con(T)$ then $T+\neg\varphi\not\vdash Con(T)$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Wow, that's amazing. Thank you!!